# Query with special characters in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with queries that contains `'` in names.

Select HTML:

```
<select id="list-skins" name = "specific_skins_list[]" multiple="multiple" style="width: 500px">
<?php
     $get_all_skins_list= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM skins_list");

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_all_skins_list)) {
         $skins_name = $row["skins_list"];
         $skins_id = $row["id"];
         $skins_name = str_replace("&#039;", "&rsquo;", $skins_name);
         echo '<option value="'.$skins_name.'">'.$skins_name.'</option>';
     }//END WHILE GET_ALL_REGIONS
 ?>
 </select>
```

POST

```
if (isset($_POST["specific_skins_list"])) {
    $query .= "
         AND skins LIKE  '%" . implode("%' or skins LIKE '%", $_POST['specific_skins_list']) ."%'
         ";
}
```

My problem is: in table `skins_list`, I have names like:

```
 i'oan , v'asilivev etc...
```

These names contain a `'` .

The query works fine if the names are normal without special characters. I found couple solutions in my search to use `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

I tried to do something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST["specific_skins_list"])) {
    $skins = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["specific_skins_list"])   ; 
    $query .= "
         AND skins LIKE  '%" . implode("%' or skins LIKE '%", $skins) ."%'
         ";
}
```

but I get this error:

> mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in... my page

And the query is like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM import_acc 
WHERE available = 'YES' AND region = 'UVAS' AND st= 'Truex' AND skins LIKE '%%' "
```

Thank you for your time.

P.S. I think the only way i can fix this is to modified all table skins_list and add manulaly  double '' to every name :D

Comment: This is why you should use prepared statements with parameters instead of concatenating variables.

Answer (score 0):

You defined the fields as "specific_skins_list[]", so it produces an array instead of a string, and that's why you get the error. mysqli_real_escape_string only works on strings.
The simplest way to solve this is to loop on this array, calling mysqli_real_escape_string on each element, e.g:

```
$skins = [];
foreach($_POST["specific_skins_list"] as $skin)
  $skins[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$skin);
```

Now your $skins variable contains properly formatted strings for an SQL query (probably).
Of course, in a real script you should do a lot more validation - you should make sure that $_POST["specific_skins_list"] is defined and is indeed an array (using isset and is_array), and that each element is a valid skin name or something (e.g. using preg_match).
Otherwise your script may generate lots of errors or your DB can be hacked if someone uses the script directly, bypassing your UI.